# How to access a excel file in CF8?

Tags: excel, coldfusion

How to read an excel file from cfm page?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you want to do. If you simply need to upload the file, you can use the `cffile` tag (CF8 documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_f_10.html#3540091)).

If you want to extract data from it, you may want to look at Ben Nadel's [POI Utility CFC](http://www.bennadel.com/projects/poi-utility.htm). (Note that it's not been updated since the release of CF9 because of the introduction of the `cfspreadsheet` tag in that version of ColdFusion.)

Comment: +1 - The POI CFC is build on the Java Apache Project of the same name - http://poi.apache.org/